# URL error in {% url ... %} when breaking line in source code

Tags: html, django

I'm working on an app in Django (2.2) and I've run into an issue with one of my html templates, where the URL doesn't work when the source code line breaks inside a {% url ... %} tag.

This is the code that doesn't work:

```
                <small><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_entry' 
                    entry.id %}">edit entry</a></small>
```

This is the error I get:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/topics/2/%7B%25%20url%20'learning_logs:edit_entry'%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20entry.id%20%25%7D
Using the URLconf defined in learning_log.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
users/
[name='index']
topics/ [name='topics']
topics/<int:topic_id>/ [name='topic']
new_topic/ [name='new_topic']
new_entry/<int:topic_id>/ [name='new_entry']
edit_entry/<int:entry_id>/ [name='edit_entry']

The current path, topics/2/{% url 'learning_logs:edit_entry' entry.id %}, didn't match any of these.
```

This is the code that works:

```
                <small><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_entry' entry.id %}">
                    edit entry</a></small>
```

Does it mean you can't break the line in source code inside {% url ... %} tags? Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: That is correct, you can not perform linebreaks in template tags.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<small>
<a href="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_entry' edit_entry=entry.id %}">
 edit entry
</a>
</small>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.